# how to force sleep or any other type of timer to execute at particular time in c++?

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, posix

I am doing socket programming in `C` and I want to do the following thing:

```
pid = fork();
if(pid == 0){
    //child process
    for(int m=0;m<2;m++){
        j=0;
        for(i=0;i<len_neighbors;i++){
            socket_des1[i] = get_socket_connection_client(hostname1, neighbor_socket[i],(char *) "udp");
            //sending data to other routers
            cout<<"\nMessage: Sending routing table to neighbor, "<<neighbors[i];
            if (send(socket_des1[i], &message1[0], message1.length(), 0) < 0){
                perror("\nError:Message sending failed\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            j++;
        }
        for(i=0;i<len_neighbors;i++){
            close(socket_des1[i]);
        }
        sleep(30);
        cout<<"Hello";
    }
}else{
    // code for parent process
}
```

So basically the process will send data to all the neighbors and the goto sleep. What is happening here is the process sends data to first neighbor and then sleeps for 30secs. How do I force the process to finish sending and then execute `sleep(30)` statement.

I am using forking for the process. And the code above is part of child process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only guess what is the problem (please add the child code creation to check), I think that when this code is executed by the first child the number of neighbors is 0, with the second the number will be 1, and so on. I would try with a sleep at the beginning so this gives enough time to the others children to fork before sending all the msg.

Comment: i have edited the code. I have only one child that loops over and sends messages to all the neighbors

Comment: I don't see any problem in the code, are you sure that the array of neighbors is properly filled ? and that len_neighbors has the correct number ?

Comment: yes so len_neighbors is 2 and it is properly filled. The thing is it calls the second neighbor send function after 30 seconds. So how do I stop the sleep function from getting control.

Comment: @Pruthvid. If len_neigbors is really 2 and the send to the second neighbor happens after 30 secs, the second send must fail since you've closed the sockets in the first path through the loop.

Comment: @Lou the close is outside the loop. @Pruthvid Are you telling me that "Message: Sending routing table to neighbor, " is printed after 30 seconds from the first one ?.. Do you have 4 prints or only 2 ?

Comment: @Agustin - I guess my point is that if he is seeing a 30 second delay, he must be leaving the inner loop to get to the sleep(30) which should then close the sockets. So it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Agustin the message is printed after every 30secs exactly no of times the len_neighbors

Answer (score 0):

It seems you try use send function with udp protocol. It is wrong. use sendto

Answer (score 0):

You are printing messages to buffered standard output stream. Maybe your messages are in the buffer untill you print \n after 30 s delay?
Try to use cerr instead of cout. Or do flush.